# Bootstrap css,how to reduce the width of "th" and "td"?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pfxcswy2/) is my html's code,I use bootstrap to design my page.

I can't reduce the width of "th" and "td",I tried to use this code `style="width:50px"` to reduce the width of "th":

```
<th class="text-center" style="width:50px">JAN</th>
```

And this code `style="width:50px"` to reduce "td":

```
<td class="text-center" style="width:50px">
   <input type="text">
</td>
```

But there is no effect,the "th" and "td" element still very wide,like this picture:
[image]

How to reduce the width of "th" and "td"?

Comment: Make sure there is no style on the input box which makes it wider than 50px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` elements are breaking your table layout.

Set the input elements inside the td as `width: 100%`

```
table td input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pfxcswy2/9/

Comment: I use this code`table td input {
  width: 40px;
}`   This is helpful!Thank you,sir!

Comment: @MadFrog: On small screens the width will remain fixed if you use width:40px, So instead use width in percentages only. use say 90%  or 80% depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

At the top th tag add width='1'
This will make the column width depending on rows content

```
<th width='1' class="text-center" style="width:50px">JAN</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try table-condensed class in your table.
The .table-condensed class makes a table more compact by cutting cell padding in half.

```
 <table border="1" class="table table-bordered text-right table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr bgcolor="#337ab7">
          <th class="text-center">No</th>
          <th class="text-center">JAN</th>
          <th class="text-center">name</th>
          <th class="text-center">size</th>
          <th class="text-center">except</th>
          <th class="text-center"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
```

This is a quick solution. See if this helps otherwise we will have to write our own css class with higher specificity.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is due to the bootstrap's styling of th and elements which is given the width of 10%.

```
.table>thead>tr>th {
width: 10%;
}
```

All we need to do is use our own style's to override the bootstrap style.
use this code in your external style sheet.It reduces the width to minimum.
Do the same for td's with small modifications according to your need.
CSS code:[ To have the same behaviour through out use below CSS code]

```
.table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, 
 .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    width:0% !important;
 }
```

[image: Overrided bootstrap Style]
But this change will be overrided everywhere you use table.Better is to give some class name for the particular row you want your new styles on.

HOPE THIS WILL HELP !

Comment: When I use your code,the right div moves to the bottom.

Comment: Write the same css for td's also.

Comment: .table>tbody>tr>td, .table>tbody>tr>th, .table>tfoot>tr>td, .table>tfoot>tr>th, .table>thead>tr>td, .table>thead>tr>th {
    width:0% !important;
}

Comment: I am no sir, We are Friends Brother. And this infact is not a complete solution.Often times we need to see where we need to make changes according to our needs as bootstrap will definitely apply its own CSS. So we keep on playing around these things and look for a solution in browser's developer tools , this way we learn also - a lot. If my answer has helped  you in any way or form do please rate. If not then don't rate Friend. Thank you :) Take care.

Comment: This is helpful!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176985/discussion-between-madfrog-and-imran-rafiq-rather).